# How can I implement a method that finds an intersection between two numeric arrays using recursion?

Tags: arrays, recursion, data-structures

I'm beginning to study recursion, and my teacher gave me this task. And I've been trying to find a solution for a week, but i couldn't make any progress so far. I did some easier exercises using recursion, but this one is a little hard for me, so I ask for you guys to help me understand which is the best way to implement this method. I'm from Brazil by the way, so, sorry for any grammatical mistakes.

Comment: People here don't mind your language as long as it's understandable and polite, but if they can't see any effort, e.g. what have you tried, how would you tackle the problem, then the downvotes will be flying in. Also an example would help to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give you a brief outline of what you can do.

Since recursion is being used for finding the intersection, **I am assuming that the two arrays are given in sorted order, and they so not have duplicate elements. I am also using 1-based index for arrays for ease of understanding.**

Here is what you can do:

1. Maintain two extra variables (`Position1` and `Position2`) for keeping track of the current position of element in the arrays during recursion.
2. First check if the current positions of elements to compare are within array limits. If they are not, we have completed our procedure.
3. Then compare the elements in current positions in both the arrays.
4. If the elements are equal, print them as we have found an intersection. Consider the next elements of both the arrays and make the corresponding recursive call.
5. Else if the current element in the first array is greater than that in the second array, we will consider the next element in the second array. Make a recursive call accordingly.
6. Else if the current element in the first array is lesser than that in the second array, we will consider the next element of the first array. Make a recursive call accordingly.

Here is a pseudocode showing the above given steps:

```
Intersection(Array1, Length1, Position1, Array2, Length2, Position2)
{
    if(Position1 > Length1 OR Position2 > Length2)
        return;
    if(Array1[Position1] == Array2[Position2])
    {
        print Array1[Position1];
        call Intersection(Array1, Length1, Position1 + 1, Array2, Length2, Position2 + 1);
    }
    else if(Array1[Position1] > Array2[Position2])
    {
        call Intersection(Array1, Length1, Position1, Array2, Length2, Position2 + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        call Intersection(Array1, Length1, Position1 + 1, Array2, Length2, Position2);
    }
}
```